# How to expand multiple list column in rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, list, expand, melt

I have a DataFrame like this:

| ID | MS | DS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 654 | 1500,10000,20000,30000 | 60,365,730 |
| 131 | 1500,10000,20000 | 60,365,730 |
| 598 | 1500,10000,20000,30000 | 60,365,730 |

The desired output looks like this:

| ID | MS | DS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 654 | 1500 | 60 |
| 654 | 10000 | 365 |
| 654 | 20000 | 730 |
| 654 | 30000 | Nan |
| 131 | 1500 | 60 |
| 131 | 10000 | 365 |
| 131 | 20000 | 730 |
| 598 | 1500 | 60 |

I have tried the following code:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

df.apply(lambda row: list(zip_longest(row['MS'], 
                                  row['DS'], 
                                  fillvalue = 'Nan')),axis = 1)
```

This did not work as expected, as it creates a Series with list values like this: `[('1500,10000,20000,30000', '60,365,730')], [('1500,10000,20000', '60,365,730')]`.

Comment: The values are in list format in both the columns  like this [1500,10000,20000,30000], i had to remove the list as stackoverflow was not letting me post the question saying 

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```py
cols = ['MS', 'DS']

dfs = [df[c].explode().str.split(',', expand=True)
       .astype('Int64')
       .stack()
       .rename(c) 
       for c in cols]

out = (pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
       .droplevel(1)
       .join(df['ID'])
       .loc[:, df.columns]
       )

out

    ID     MS    DS
0  654   1500    60
0  654  10000   365
0  654  20000   730
0  654  30000  <NA>
1  131   1500    60
1  131  10000   365
1  131  20000   730
2  598   1500    60
2  598  10000   365
2  598  20000   730
2  598  30000  <NA>
```

**Explanation**

1. Inside a list comprehension, for each column of `['MS', 'DS']`:

   - use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)  to get list elements into multiple rows;
   - use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on `','` and set `expand` to `True` to get the result in multiple columns;
   - chain [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with `Int64` to turn what will be *string* values into proper integers, while allowing for `NaN` values (the shorter sequences will have these for columns not "reached");
   - apply [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get a `pd.Series` result (with column values now as a second level index);
   - add [`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) to restore the original column name.
2. Join both `Series`, add non-exploded column, and re-order:

   - use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) along `axis=1` (columns)
   - apply [`df.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to drop the added index level;
   - use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to re-add the non-exploded column `ID`;
   - pass `df.columns` to [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to reset the column order.

**Data used**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [654, 131, 598],
    'MS': [['1500,10000,20000,30000'], ['1500,10000,20000'], 
           ['1500,10000,20000,30000']],
    'DS': [['60,365,730'], ['60,365,730'], 
           ['60,365,730']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    ID                        MS            DS
0  654  [1500,10000,20000,30000]  [60,365,730]
1  131        [1500,10000,20000]  [60,365,730]
2  598  [1500,10000,20000,30000]  [60,365,730]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df[["MS","DS"]] = df[["MS","DS"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(","),axis=1)
df["final"] = df[["MS","DS"]].apply(lambda x: list(zip_longest(x["MS"], x["DS"])),axis=1)
df = df.explode("final")
df[["MS","DS"]] = df["final"].values.tolist()
```

**Out:**

```
    ID     MS    DS
0  654   1500    60
0  654  10000   365
0  654  20000   730
0  654  30000  None
1  131   1500    60
1  131  10000   365
1  131  20000   730
2  598   1500    60
2  598  10000   365
2  598  20000   730
2  598  30000  None
```